# Passing KeyPress/Enter event from column to cell renderer

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am defining a grid in which for the one of the columns I am using a cellRenderer to display an . While everything works fine I would like add the functionality where in if a user navigates/focuses on that cell ( defined by this column ) and hits ENTER the cursor/focus should make the input text editable. My knowledge of angular/ag-grid is very very basic, so please do excuse me if there are any fundamental flaws.

Here is my colDef

```
testField : ColDef {
    headerName: 'testField',
    field: ' testField',
    cellRenderer: 'inputCellRenderer'
}
```

InputCellRenderer.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-input-field',
    template: '<mat-form-field>
                 <input mat-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model" [(ngModelChange)}="HandleChange()">{{model}}</input>
               </mat-form-field>
})

export InputRenderer extends ICellRendererAngularComp {
    public model:string;

    refresh(params : any): void {
       // refresh logic
    }

    agInit(params : any) : void {
       // initialize "model"
    }

    HandleChange(): void {
        // handle model change logic
    }
}
```

When a user focuses on a cell defined by "testField" and presses ENTER I want the cursor/focus to be on the input text field. If I make the column editable by adding

```
   editable: true
```

it does not help as it does not pass the change in state to the rendered component.

I need to do something similar to this in the InputRenderer to enable focus

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-input-field',
    template: '<mat-form-field>
                 <input #inputText mat-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model" [(ngModelChange)}="HandleChange()">{{model}}</input>
               </mat-form-field>
})

export InputRenderer extends ICellRendererAngularComp {
    public model:string;
    @ViewChild('inputText') textField : ElementRef

     /* I THINK THIS NEEDS TO BE CALLED AS A CALLBACK FROM THE GRID CELL. GRID CELL SHOULD LISTEN to KEYPRESS/ENTER events and call this */
    focusCallBack() {
       this.textField.nativeElement.focus()
    }

    refresh(params : any): void {
       // refresh logic
    }

    agInit(params : any) : void {
       // initialize "model"
    }

    HandleChange(): void {
        // handle model change logic
    }
}
```

Any help on achieving this will be very helpful

Comment: I am using ag-grid. However the rendered cell is using angular material input to take in user inputs

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to use `ICellEditorAngularComp` for editing it, while it seems that you are using `ICellRendererAngularComp`.
2. Enable editing by `editable: true` in `ColDef`.

```javascript
testField: ColDef = {
  headerName: 'testField',
  field: ' testField',
  cellEditorFramework: inputCellRenderer,
  editable: true
}
```

> Reference: [Angular Editor Components](https://www.ag-grid.com/example-angular-editor/)

```
@ViewChild('inputText') textField: ElementRef;
```

3. Set the focus programmatically in `afterGuiAttached` function of the editor component.

```javascript
  afterGuiAttached?(params?: IAfterGuiAttachedParams): void {
      this.textField.nativeElement.select();
  }
```

The third step will set your keyboard focus to the textbox.

Comment: Thank you, Paritosh. This seems to be the right way to approach this. I am still working on the functionality and will update this thread once it is fully functional